# Scala worksheet does not evaluate object in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

This very simple worksheet content demonstrates the issue:

```
object Test {
 println("This does not print!")
  add(5, 6)
}

println("This however prints!")
add(5, 6)

def add(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b
```

Results from the above worksheet content are:

```
defined module Test

This however prints!
res0: Unit = ()
res1: Int = 11

add: add[](val a: Int,val b: Int) => Int
```

Based on [JetBrains official website Scala Worksheets example](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Working+with+Scala+Worksheet) and every other reliable resource I've found (like [Martin Odresky's own examples in Functional Programming in Scala course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/progfun1)), I would expect the contents of `object Test` to execute. My software is:

- OS X El Capitan
- IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2
- SBT Plugin 1.8.0
- SBT Version 0.13.12
- Scala Plugin 2016.2.1
- Scala Version 2.11.8

Comment: `I would expect the contents of object Test to execute` I would not expect it to execute. Worksheet is fancy repl. I would never expect repl to do that

Comment: Well, all the examples I find (including the page on JetBrains website itself) show worksheets to work precisely like that. I've added it to my answer.

Comment: Apparently the different behaviour between IntelliJ and the videos is due to the code running in Eclipse in the videos (see questions on this issue in Coursera's forums: a staff member suggests to run the code outside of a singleton object in the scala worksheet).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
object Test {
  println("This does not print!") 
  add(5, 6)

  println("This however prints!")
  add(5, 6)

  def add(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b
}
```

How the worksheet works is, that if you define an object and nothing defined outside the `object` scope, it will execute it as `Test extends App`. Which is what the intellij page displays

If you have any statement outside the `object` scope, it is then treated as any other `object` and compiler will initialize it like anything else. This is what you are experiencing.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the answer! How would I execute an object that has been defined (I believe it's singleton)?

Comment: You can execute by just taking its name like : `Test`

Comment: The body of `object` is nothing but constructor body. So the first time you call it, the body will be executed when the class loader loads it. 
Subsequently, it wont call the constructor initialization the next time.

Answer (score 15):

I was able to evaluate the Scala work sheet by changing the Scala worksheet settings.

- change run type to plain (original it was REPL)

You can get to settings by clicking the settings icon on the Scala worksheet.

Comment: Did not work for me: I have the same problem as the OP, even though the Scala Worksheet settings is checked on "Run worksheet in the compiler process (Plain mode only)". I am working with IntelliJ CE 2020.1.1, Scala 2.12.10 and sbt 1.3.10 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 9):

The scala worksheet executes the contents of the object test{....} if all the code is inside that object. If there is some code outside the object, it will just define that Test object (and not run it).

```
object Test {
  println("This does not print!")
  def add(a: Int, b: Int): Int = {print("Sum:" + a + b); a + b}
  add(2, 2)
}

// defined the above Test object

Test // executes the Test object
```